# is Intel Iris 1536 MB better than NVIDIA 8600M?

Tags: graphics, gpu, system-requirements

I was looking at a few games on steam and came across one that read "ATI Radeon HD 2400 or better / NVidia 8600M or better", my macbook has an Intel Iris 1536 mb (8Gb DDR3) and I was wondering if it's good enough to run the game

Comment: What research have you done to find out how the GPU in your Macbook stacks up in comparison with the GPU requirements of the Steam games?

Comment: *Any* Intel Gpu is one that is built-in to the cpu and are generally deemed inferior to discreet GPUs. The issue here may be that it *requires* that your Mac have a discreet GPU, which it does not and unless you are willing to spend big bucks on an external (Thunderbolt) GPU system you can't add one.